# Make copy of a struct variable in C

Tags: c, struct

I want to save the record element of a heap in a struct _Record variable then delete that record, after deleting the record I want to return the saved record. How can I achieve this?

```
struct _Record
{
    int id;
    char name[15];
    char surname[15];
    char email[26];
    int grade;
};
```

//struct _Record saved = hp->elem[0].record; here I try to assign to another variable called saved.

```
struct _Record deleteNode(minHeap *hp) {
    struct _Record saved;
    if(hp->size) {
        saved = hp->elem[0].record;

        hp->elem[0] = hp->elem[--(hp->size)] ;
        hp->elem = realloc(hp->elem, hp->size * sizeof(node)) ;
        heapify(hp, 0) ;
        printf("%d %s %s %s %d",saved.id,saved.name,saved.surname,saved.grade);
        return saved;
        
    } else {
        printf("\nMin Heap is empty!\n") ;
        free(hp->elem);
        return saved; 
    }
}
```

Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
int main(){

    minHeap heap = initMinHeap();
    struct _Record rec;
   
    rec.id=1;
    strcpy(rec.name,"tName");
    strcpy(rec.surname,"tSurname");
    strcpy(rec.email,"email");
    rec.grade=10;

    node node;
    node.record = rec;
    insertNode(&heap,node);

    struct _Record saved;
    saved = deleteNode(&heap);
    printf("%s","\n");
    printf("%d %s %s %s %d",saved.id,saved.name,saved.surname,saved.email,saved.grade);
    return -1; 
}
```

**NOTE:** Other heap functions work correctly. There is a problem with returning the saved node in deleteNode.

Results I get: Nothing

Results I want to get: "1 tName tSurname email 10"

Comment: What do you mean "a heap"? The data type heap or the heap memory where you malloc the items? What's `minHeap`? Isn't `struct _Record saved = hp->elem[0].record;` followed by `return` doing exactly what you want? Please clarify what results you get and what results you want to get.

Comment: The function is incorrectly written btw, it must always return an item. You should do something like `struct record saved = NULL; if(hp->size) saved = ...; else { ... } return saved;`.

Comment: And unrelated to the question, we aren't allowed to name variables with leading underscore followed by an upper-case letter. That's reserved for the library implementation.

Comment: @Lundin yes it is what I want but it does not work. when I try to print saved record nothing is printed.

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] that shows this behavior?

Comment: @Lundin: "*You should do something like `struct record saved = NULL;`*" how should this work, as `record` is not a pointer?.

Comment: "*Minimal Reproducible Example:*" unfortunately not, as all but one functions are unknown.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I have made a mistake with printf() function.

```
printf("%d %s %s %s %d",saved.id,saved.name,saved.surname,saved.grade);
```

I am giving 4 parameter  to printf function but it must be 5.

```
printf("%d %s %s %s %d \n",rec.id,rec.name,rec.surname,rec.email,rec.grade);
```

Also, @rkrahl's answer is correct too.

Comment: If you compile with gcc it ususally examines the format string and counts the arguments, so you'd get a warning.

Comment: I compiled it with gcc but I don't know why it didn't give me a warning. Thanks.